# flexbox isnt displayed properly in react

Tags: css, reactjs

i am trying to create a flexbox with image in one pill and some text in another pill. here's the code i have written in react->

```
import NavbarTop from "../navbar/navbar";
import "./style.css";
import React from 'react';


function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavbarTop />

      <div id="titleTextDiv" className="d-flex">
        <div className="p-2 flex-fill">
          <img className="titlePic" src="home/titleLogo.png" />
        </div>
        <div className="p-2 flex-fill">
          <span className="titleText">Dumpster<br></br>Dive</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      
      
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

style.css

```
#titleTextDiv {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.titlePic {
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
}

.titleText {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

but the flexbox isnt working. the text is displayed under the image for some reason. can someone guide me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have display: flex; set anywhere in this component? If not, then the css doesn't know to put it into a flexbox. Add the display: flex; to the #titleTextDiv and they should appear next to each other.

```
#titleTextDiv {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.titlePic {
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
}

.titleText {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xugd1p?file=src/style.css)

Comment: it worked thanks. i cant believe i missed such a trivial thing.